# Property 'render' does not exist on type 'typeof import

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element

I have two components `my-element` and `my-test-element`

On the `render` function of `my-element` i am calling the following method:

```
renderWidget(){
      import("./my-test-element").then(MyTestElement => {
          MyTestElement.render();
      });
}
```

However here I get the following error:

> property 'render' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/myRepo/Project/src/my-test-element")'.

Here is my `my-test-element.ts`:

```
import {LitElement, html, customElement, property, css} from 'lit-element';
@customElement('my-test-element')
export class MyTestElement extends LitElement {
    static styles = css`
    :host {
      display: block;
      border: solid 1px gray;
      padding: 16px;
      max-width: 800px;
    }
  `;

    /**
     * The name to say "Hello" to.
     */
    @property()
    name = 'World';

    /**
     * The number of times the button has been clicked.
     */
    @property({type: Number})
    count = 0;

    render() {
        return html`
      <h1>Hello, ${this.name}!</h1>
    `;
    }
}

declare global {
    interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
        'my-test-element': MyTestElement;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: `MyTestElement` is a named  export. Try `MyTestElement.MyTestElement.render()`

Comment: @AdamAzad Hey yeah that did change the error message to an expected argument error however i am not quite sure what that means since it takes no arguments?

Comment: `MyTestElement` is a class. It should have an instance before calling `render`. Also to make the code neater, change the named export to default.

Comment: `import("./my-test-element").then(mod => { const e = new mod.MyTestElement; e.render(); });`.

Comment: This looks interesting, Can you share the usecase for such implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic `import` returns the module, not the element, as there can be multiple exports.

Try:

```
renderWidget(){
      import("./my-test-element").then(module => {
          module.MyTestElement.render();
      });
}
```

However, this really isn't how you use a custom element - loading that module registers the tag to load that element, so you can do:

```
await import("./my-test-element");
const instanceOfMyElement = document.createElement('my-test-element');
```

Then `render` will fire automatically when you add `instanceOfMyElement` to the page.